# Glassfish starting up

Tags: java, glassfish, netbeans-7

I tried to start with JSF programming today, working with Netbeans 7.0.1. 
Now, I made my first application with the help of a tutorial, but my glassfish server does not start.

If I click in Netbeans at Servers on Start (See [here](http://www.bilderload.com/daten/unbenanntZSBBU.png)), nothing happens. If I run my application, it tells me `Starting GlassFish Server 3.1`, but also after about ten minutes, nothing happens.

So what can I do to solve this problem? I also tried to install netbeans once again, but it doesn´t helped.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that a Glassfish server is installed on your system, otherwise Netbeans wouldn't show the GF node as shown in your picture.

Try to start Glassfish from the command line. Find your GF installation directory. There is a subfolder *bin*.

Inside this folder there is the asadmin tool. Try the following command:

```
asadmin start-domain
```

This will start GF's standard domain *domain1*. It should end up with something like "Domain started successfully". If not, we could look further.

Comment: Hello again... Sorry but after a restart of the system, the same problem...
I tried your suggest and get the following output: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/33/unbenaannt.jpg/

Comment: This may be related to your gf installation path. Either there is an issue with the access right or with the space in your path. I remember long time ago had a similiar problem and from that on always installed GF in root directory, e.g. c:\glassfish31